# Pandas DataFrame slow to show shape or dtypes

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe

I'm very new to `python` and `pandas`. Any guidance, comment, and suggestion are appreciated!

Here is my issue: it takes couple minutes to return the result after I call `df.shape` or `df.dtypes`. The `DataFrame` has **1,610,658** rows and **5** columns. Three columns are stored as `int64`, one as `float64`, and one as `datetime64`.

I used the following codes to practice load & transform in `python`. Both load and transform have good performance, but I met this issue when I checked the output.

*Update 1:*

After setting some columns as index, the `df.shape` time drops from **80+s** down to **1.7s**, but the `df.dtypes` still stay at 80+s

```
import pandas as pd

###############
# Load
###############
raw = pd.read_csv("data.zip", compression='zip')

###############
# Transform
###############

payment_method = {
   "Cash": 1
   "Card": 2
}

df = raw. \
    assign(
        # Encode site ids to int. Only two sites in this data
        site     = (raw.site == "A").astype(int),
        # Encode payment types to int
        payment  = 
            [payment_method.get(k, 0) for k in raw.payment],
        # Rescale values
        amount   = raw.amount / 1e6,
        # Convert integer date key to datetime
        sold_date= pd.to_datetime(
            [str(dt) for dt in raw. sold_date],
            format="%Y%m%d")
    )

###############
# Check point
###############

df.shape # pain point I. Took minutes to return
# Out[9]: (1610658, 5)

df.dtypes # pain point II
# Out[10]: 
# site                       int64
# acct_key                   int64
# sold_date         datetime64[ns]
# amount                   float64
# payment                    int64
```

If I convert the data frame to `numpy.ndarray`, I can instantly get the result. I think I must miss something. Please give me some direction.

Thanks a lot!

System: OS X 10.12
Python: 3.6.1
Numpy:  1.12
Pandas: 0.20.2
Jupyter console: 5.1.0

Comment: How about if you just execute print(df)? Can it be related to some lazy evaluation? Do you try the numpy thing after calling the shape attribute?

Comment: @ayhan Thank you for your reply. 1. `print(df)` gives me the result right away, so as slicing and other data manipulations. Based on my limited observation, it only slows down when extracting metadata, like `<tab>` for the attribute and method list in `IPython`. 2. I don't know too much about lazy evaluation in `Python`, sorry. 3. Very thing works fine in `Numpy`

Comment: Do you have Jedi installed?  (You might not have installed it directly, but it might have come in with jupyter or ipython.)

Comment: @DSM Yes, `Jedi` is in my list. I set up my environment through `conda`. Thank you for your reply

Comment: @RichardH Do you have sample data with which the problem can be reproduced? Did you finally find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try to reduce the size of your DataFrame:

```
int_columns = df.select_dtypes(include=["int"]).columns
df[int_columns] = df[int_columns].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='unsigned')
float_columns = df.select_dtypes(include=["float"]).columns
df[float_columns] = df[float_columns].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='float')
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can reduce the size of your dataframe using as @Hai mentioned with type conversions. Also consider using `pd.Categorical` data type in place of strings. This replaces strings with integers under the hood, which probably has the most dramatic improvement in reduced memory usage. More here: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/pandas-big-data/
2. You can also reduce the data size by excluding unnecessary columns at the import step using `pd.read_csv()` with the `usecols` parameter.
3. If you want to get row and/or column counts without reading the entire dataset at once, you can use a technique called lazy evaluation/using a generator, which reads one line at a time. I like to do this for huge files that I need to inspect before opening and analyzing further.

The generator approach

```py
num_rows = 0

with open(r'/Users/Username/Downloads/data_set.csv') as file:
    num_cols = len(file.readline().split(','))
    try:
        while next(file):
            num_rows += 1
    except StopIteration:
        pass

shape = (num_rows, num_cols)
print(shape)
```

is basically a manual but less memory-intensive implementation of pandas `df.shape`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/Username/Downloads/data_set.csv')
print(df.shape)
```